# Secure way to communicate to web server

Tags: c#, wpf, webserver

I am new to all this web stuff and WPF in general so bear with me.  I have written a desktop WPF application which processes some user interactions.  I need to log a lot of these interactions and it's metadata and I was doing that locally (just logging and dumping it into a file) but I would like to upload this somewhere onto my web hosting so I can monitor it remotely.  It would also need to be secure so no one else but me can view the data.  Is there some framework I can leverage for this?  Or just straight up use HTTPS/SFTP to dump this data there?